# How can I improve my looting system?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to create some loot when you open a chest. The objective is to determine what I loot.

Actually, I made some categories: `FOOD`, `ARMOR`, `WEAPON`, `TOOL`, `BOOKS`, `POTIONS`, `OTHERS`.

Each categories as list of item. Each item as a "rarity" value, which goes from 0 to 1. (0 = less, 1 = more)

When I loot, I determine how many stack I will drop. Then, for each stack I do:

1. I determine a category from all available (i.e. with item on it)
2. I get a random item from the list of the determined category
3. I generate a random number between 0 and 1, and if the generated number is upper than the "rarity", it skip this item, and go back to step 2
4. I now have an item according to rarity

The problem is the actual system gives too many of potions & books according to what it does. I made categories to don't have 4 times armor, and no food, but this system doesn't seem to be the right choice.

I would like to refactor how it's generated, to globally have like 5% of potions, 10% of books, 30% of food, 30% or armor etc, have different items each time (not always the same armor) and with a rarity per item. The objective is to have lot of probability to have some armor pieces, but less to have diamond than iron or leather. But also, have little of food, weapon etc to be able to play normally (as with only armor, I'll not go far).

What should I change to make it better?

*Quick precision: Each category has a different amount of item (weapon as 14, book as 4 etc).*

Comment: I believe this answer needs more details. While you've partially explained how your current system works and a flaw you perceive in it, we don't know what your actual goal is.

Comment: @Onyz I just updated my post, hope it's better now!

Comment: It looks better now, to me. :)

Comment: what are you using for this system? sounds like you're doing it all manually. Have you had a look at [loot tables](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Loot_table)? They are literally made for this kind of thing and there are [handy generators for them](https://misode.github.io/loot-table/), too.

Comment: @Plagiatus I'm in Java as I do it programmatically. Loot table seems not available for my server version (1.8.8), maybe I can reproduce them but I'm not sure

Comment: yeah true they were introduced in 1.9. You maybe should've mentioned you're using an almost 8 year old version of the game and that's you're actually doing it programmatically and looking for a modding way to do it. Maybe a different SE site would then be better, like gamedev or just SO.

Comment: @Plagiatus I didn't mention it because I'm more looking for the behavior than the real code. I can code it myself, but idk what to code/change. And as it's more the "algorithm"/way, it wasn't not necessary to precise the MC version